# What is InfoOfFriends[]?

Tags: java

```
public static InfoOfFriends[] friendsInfo = null;
```

In the above line I didn't get what is happening there? Why there is InfoOfFriends[] because InfoOfFriends is a class which I discovered from the code? Please help me understand.

Comment: it's an array of InfoOfFriends objects.

Comment: that is an array of InfoOfFriends objects http://stackoverflow.com/a/1200646/3711660

Comment: an array of InfoOfFriends objects. :)

Comment: Ermm ... I think it is time to read an introductory Java textbook or tutorial ... properly.

Answer (score 0):

That line is declaring an array of `InfoOfFriends` objects. The general rule for this is is:

```
Type[] arrayName = new Type[elementCount];
```

See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for further reading about arrays in Java.